# Customer Churn Measurement

Tags: measurement, churn

Looking at trying to determine the dependent variable in a customer churn problem for a car dealership.

Right now my customers make two types of purchases (oil changes, maintenance) and big ticket purchases (purchase of a car).

Trying to determine the probability that a customer has left for good if I have not seen them in a month, in 6 months, etc. Looking at this at the most basic level (just if the customer shows up for a service etc.)

Thinking that this involved looking at the time in between events at the minimum but a little stuck on how this translates into "the customer never showing up again."

Requesting advise in terms of the approach (bayesian, frequentist, etc) and a method for measuring.